# How do i use Qvarient in cpp for set functions

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to pass values from qml to set function written in Qt cpp, the values that will be passed is of different data types, example int or string, I will be writing only one set function in cpp which will take this values and return Qstring or int or double.How can I write a code for this.

Answer (score 1):

C++  does know of two types:

- [`QVariant`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html)
- [`QJSValue`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html)

which might be the value, that you passed... That depends on you.
Both of them have various methods to test for their content, and to convert to this.
See the linked documentations for this.

You may even store the passed value as the corresponding type, without the need of conversion (up to the time, you need it for calculations in C++) It depends on, what you will do with it, to find the right choice.